# spawns some threads and performs a calculation in the thread worker function

Tags: c

I am working on this program that spawns some threads and performs a calculation in the thread worker function. It then takes the results and sums them together. I tried to complete the run_threads function :
1) Spawn n threads which call runMe which pass in a pointer to int (int*) pointing to consecutive values from (0 to n - 1)

2) Wait for all threads to finish and collect the exit codes (another int* cast to void*)
3) Return the sum of the exit codes from run_threads() 
The code looks a little like this:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int has_run[10] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

void runMe(int *arg) {
  int value = (*arg);
  assert(value >= 0 && value < 5 && "Bad argument passed to 'runMe()!'");

  has_run[value] = 1;

  int *ret = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
  *ret = value * value; 

  pthread_exit((void*)ret);
}

int run_threads(int n) {

     pthread_t threads[n];
    int thr_args[n];
    int total = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        thr_args[i] = i;
        pthread_create(threads+i, NULL, (void*)runMe, thr_args+i);

    }
    for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
    {

        void *res = NULL;
        pthread_join(threads[j], &res);

        int *ires = res;


        total += thr_args[j];
        free(ires);
    }
    return total;

}

int main (int argc, char **argv) { 

  int sum = run_threads(5);

  int correct = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    if(has_run[i]) correct++;
  }

  printf("%d %d", correct, sum);

  return 0;
}
```

The output is supposed to be 5 ,30
I got 5, 10
I guess that there is a memory leak? Could you please pointed out where I did wrong in run_threads function?

Comment: I suggest you do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your code, especially the loop where you join the threads and gets their result.

Comment: As for memory leaks, that would happen if you forget to `free` memory that you have allocated with `malloc`.

Comment: The cast to (void*) is not proper at all. The prototype of the callback must be **exactly** compatible with the one that will be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing: `total += thr_args[j]` and `thr_args` contains [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] so it is correct that the sum is 10.